# Resolve Jboss data source configuration issue

Tags: jdbc, jboss, datasource, war, jbpm

After configuring the datasources in the **jboss 5.0 AS**, I deployed the **jbpm web application**.
Im getting the the exception.

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: mapped-name is required for simpleds of deployment webapple.war
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXmlResourceEnvRefs(WebResourceHand
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXml(WebResourceHandler.java:325)
```

The web.xml configuration is

```
      <resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>simpleds</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

The mysql-ds.xml configuration is

```
   <datasources><xa-datasource>
<jndi-name>simpleds</jndi-name>
<xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
<xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</xa-datasource-property>
<user-name>abc</user-name>
<password>abc</password></xa-datasource></datasources>
```

Comment: In Jboss5, Registering the datasource in jboss-web.xml,  instead of mentioning the datasource in web.xml resolves the "mapped-name required" exception. But now im getting the exception ** `Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hiber
nate.ejb.HibernatePersistence cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`**. seems to be a dependency problem.but im not sure which jar needs to be removed.kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: That was due to that the jboss avoiding the dependency jars that are added in the war lib and adding the jboss-classloading.xml in the web-inf has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While deploying a web application in JBoss 5AS, We have to define the datasource in jboss-web.xml in web-inf.

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jboss-web><resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>java:simpleds</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <jndi-name>java:simpleds</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```