# What is JBOSS- "Empty name segment is not allowed for java" error

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss7.x, jndi, web-deployment

I am newbee to JBOSS developement and tring to run a project from eclipse but I am getting **"Empty name segment is not allowed for java"** error. I know such error comes when our jndi resource name is empty but in such case it specifies as  **"env"** and not **"java"** which is in my case. Posting my stacktrace  below. I am using JBOSS 7.1 version.

```
14:34:04,440 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011001: Could not resolve resource-env-ref java:/TransactionManager
        14:34:04,440 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."workflow.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."workflow.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "workflow.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:743) [rt.jar:1.6.0_51]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty name segment is not allowed for java
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceName.of(ServiceName.java:85) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceName.append(ServiceName.java:112) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.as.naming.deployment.ContextNames.buildServiceName(ContextNames.java:178)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.deployment.ContextNames$BindInfo.<init>(ContextNames.java:190)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.deployment.ContextNames$BindInfo.<init>(ContextNames.java:181)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.deployment.ContextNames.bindInfoFor(ContextNames.java:124)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.deployment.ContextNames.bindInfoForEnvEntry(ContextNames.java:165)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deployPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:319)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.addPuService(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:258)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.handleWarDeployment(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:194)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deploy(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:118)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more

14:34:04,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "workflow.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"workflow.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"workflow.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"workflow.war\""}}
    14:34:04,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
    JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."workflow.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."workflow.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "workflow.war"

 14:34:04,471 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"workflow.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"workflow.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"workflow.war\""}}}}
14:34:04,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment workflow.war in 184ms
```

I see one warning saying that `JBAS011001: Could not resolve resource-env-ref java:/TransactionManager` but dont think error is caused by it.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Zebronix_777

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve Jboss data source configuration issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112500/resolve-jboss-data-source-configuration-issue)

Comment: Did you define the datasource in `jboss-web.xml` in `web-inf` Folder

Comment: @09Q71AO534 No I dont have any `jboss-web.xml`  file in my project but I have mentioned all datasources in `web-inf/classes/meta-inf/persistance.xml`

Comment: Do you have a `web.xml` in your project? Try following the approach which was as mentioned in the other question. You also can load the datasources from `standalone.xml`. But lets go step-by-step and then we will see what makes that behave like that

Comment: @09Q71AO534 I have solved this issue. I need to remove `java:/` prefix from the datasources mentioned in standalone.xml. It got solved.

Comment: Good to hear. Cool ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to remove java:/ prefix from the datasources mentioned in standalone.xml. It got solved. Because in `persistance.xml` it was without that prefix.